# How to get a list of all the url parameters with their values in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, parameters

In my asp.net c# solution, I want to get a dictionary of all the url parameters, where the key is the parameter name and the value is the parameter value. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Across the entire solution or just in context of a single request like /page?key1=value1&key2=value2

Comment: Whats the difference? (but I think I mean of a single request)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need HttpUtility.ParseQueryString

```
NameValueCollection qscollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
```

you can use this to get the querystring value itself:

```
 Request.Url.Query
```

To put it together

```
NameValueCollection qscollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
```

More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx

The harder manual way without using the builtin method is this:

```
NameValueCollection queryParameters = new NameValueCollection();
string[] querySegments = queryString.Split('&');
foreach(string segment in querySegments)
{
   string[] parts = segment.Split('=');
   if (parts.Length > 0)
   {
      string key = parts[0].Trim(new char[] { '?', ' ' });
      string val = parts[1].Trim();

      queryParameters.Add(key, val);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I often get into the same problem. I always end up doing it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> allRequestParamsDictionary = Request.Params.AllKeys.ToDictionary(x => x, x => Request.Params[x]);
```

This gives all params for the request, including QueryString, Body, ServerVariables and Cookie variables. For only QueryString do this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> queryStringDictionary = Request.QueryString.AllKeys.ToDictionary(x => x, x => Request.Params[x]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `HttpRequest.QueryString` object is already a collection. Basically a NameValueCollection. Check **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx)** for a more detailed explanation on MSDN. To convert this collection in to a dictionary you could add an extension method as follows.

```
    public static class NameValueCollectionExtension
    {

        public static IDictionary<string, string> ToDictionary(this NameValueCollection sourceCollection)
        {
            return sourceCollection.Cast<string>()
                     .Select(i => new { Key = i, Value = sourceCollection[i] })
                     .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);

        }

    }
```

Then you could basically just do the following since Request.QueryString is basically a NameValueCollection

```
IDictionary<string,string> dc = Request.QueryString.ToDictionary();
```