# How to check url contains query string or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check whether the url has querystring values `?` or not.

If query string value is not present, if it's a plain url, it should redirect to some other page, so that if somebody accesses the page directly they should be redirected to some other page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"]))
    {
        uniqueid = Request.QueryString["val"];
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("proformainvoice.aspx");
    }

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        fillproformadata();
    }
}
```

Comment: NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString);

Comment: giving error - cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' to 'string'

Comment: try to put var instead of NameValueCollection qscoll

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226275/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-url-parameters-with-their-values-in-asp-net-c check this link

Comment: System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Can you please show me what you write ?

Comment: NameValueCollection qscollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);...how to use it

Comment: did you get collection of parameters and their values on that list ?

Comment: NameValueCollection qscollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
            var count = qscollection.Count; the count will be zero if there is no querystring values

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HasKeys` method of `Request.QueryString` to check if url contains `QueryString` or not.

```
bool hasKeys = Request.QueryString.HasKeys();
if(hasKeys)
{
 //your code     
}
else
{
 //your code
}
```